# Component moving and resizing using Adorner, AdorrnerLayer, AdornerDecorator, Thumb in WinRT XAML/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am developing a paint-like application for Win 8. I am using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools) WPF app as a reference.

It uses `AdornerDecorator` & `Thumb` classes for moving and resizing components; are these available in WinRT?  They seem not to be available; assuming that's the case, are there any workarounds available?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the adorner layer in WPF is just a layer on top of all other controls. You could just put all such adorners together with the controls they adorn or try to create your own adorner layer using a Popup and making sure you use IsHitTestVisible="False" wherever you could obscure access to other controls with your adorners.

Comment: I am not getting your answer :(

Comment: There seems to be a [Thumb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.thumb.aspx) control in WinRT. The concept of adorners never made it to Silverlight or WinRT/XAML. Adorners exist as a sort of a second set of layers on top of all the non-adorner parts of the UI. It should be very easy to recreate similar behaviors by creating your own second layer - using a Popup, Grid, Canvas or whatever method you want. It might be difficult however to directly reuse WPF XAML code that uses adorners in Silverlight or WinRT/XAML.

Comment: Thank you Filip, can you guide me something how can I use Grid or Popup for resizing the components drawn on canvas ?

Comment: You would open a full-screen Popup (just set its Width/Height to screen size), put something like a Canvas as the Child of the Popup, then you can use the Thumbs probably similar way to how it's done in that test app. I would assume that clicking on an object in the scene shows these thumbs and some sort of a rectangle in the adorner layer (your Canvas in a Popup) and moving the thumbs moves/sizes the selected object.

Comment: Thanks for you idea but I am not a pro developer so I can't code that. I have uploaded my app's source code on codeproject, when it will be reviewed I will inform you and then you please help me with code for component moving and resizing.